# Relaunch program when grep returns a result

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to write a little bash script that launch a wine .exe file (Photoshop). During the launch, if there is a boot error, the message "Assertion failed" is displayed.

The concept would be:

1. I launch Photoshop using wine

`wine64 "/home/artik/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe"`

2. I grep the output, to see if a boot error occurs:

`2>&1 | grep -i Assertion`

3. If there is an error, I stop the execution of wine using `pipefail`, and try to relaunch photoshop
   Looping this till it boots.

I tried to write a little script that is obviously wrong. How to make it works?

```
#!/bin/sh

set -euxo pipefail

wine64 "/home/artik/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe" 2>&1 | grep -i -L Assertion

if [ Assertion failed ]
then
        wine64 "/home/artik/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe" 2>&1 | grep -i -L Assertion
fi
```

Comment: You might explain what the current behavior is.

Comment: why not just `until wine64 "/home/artik/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe"; do :; done`?

Comment: @l'L'l: Actually the script doesn't work. but the concept of what I'd like is explained. @oguz ismail: The problem is this error doesn't kill the process. So I need to grep ```Assertion failed``` and if I catch a return, kill the actual launch to retry another one

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

```
while grep -q Assertion < <(wine64 ... 2>&1)
do
  pkill wine64
done
```

`grep -q` will immediately exit with success when `Assertion` is found, and since the input is from a process substitution, it will then not wait for `wine64` to exit. This causes the loop to be entered and Wine to be restarted.

If the program exits without `grep` finding `Assertion`, then `grep` exits with failure causing the loop to stop.

Comment: `grep` will not return a value until `wine64...` terminates.  "It will not wait for it to exit" is incorrect.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I read I have to use  ```set -euxo pipefail``` and/or ```grep -L``` but I can't figure out how to use them

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'm not able to see that behavior. When I do e.g. `grep -q Assertion < <(echo Assertion; sleep 300)` it exits immediately

Comment: @Artik Can you please be more specific? Do you get an error message? Does the program start but not restart?

Comment: `grep -q Assertion < <(echo Assertion; sleep 300)` will indeed return immediately, but `grep -q Assertion < <(echo foo; sleep 300)` will not, nor will `grep Assertion < <(echo Assertion; sleep 300)`.  So your answer is valid!  It's the short circuiting of `-q` that makes that work.  Interesting technique!